# Как получить массив родительских таблиц для DataTable используя LINQ/lambda

Tags: c#, linq

Как получить массив родительских таблиц для таблицы из `DataSet` используя LINQ/lambda? С `foreach` понятно

```
foreach (DataRelation item in table.ParentRelations)
{
   parentname_id.Add(item.ParentTable.TableName + "_Id");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var list = table.ParentRelations
    .Cast<DataRelation>()
    .Select(x => x.ParentTable.TableName + "_Id")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: У `ParentRelations` нет select

Comment: Можно вызвать Cast<DataRelation>() после ParentRelations.

Comment: @ApInvent спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще попробовать через `.OfType<>()`

```
var list = table.ParentRelations
.OfType<DataRelation>()
.Select(x => x.ParentTable.TableName + "_Id");
```